# How to create new contracts (contract2a, b, c, etc) from a function in contract1 and then access the new contracts

Tags: solidity

This is my first question here and I’ll try to keep it specific.

I have a “Baker” contract that has a function that makes a new “Cookie” contract. I deploy it in Remix and have problems interacting with the new Cookie contracts that are made.

**Expected behavior:**

- Use bakeNewCookie function to create a new contract and pass it’s state variable “CookieName” a string so that I can identify it later.
- When i “bakeNewCookie” the new Cookie contract has a constructor that defines it’s state variable “CookieAddress” with address(this) (I want to access each Cookie contract via the contract address).
- Then I want to use the “myCookieAddress” function which takes the address from one of the new Cookie contracts and gives me the “CookieName” variable of said Cookie contract.

**Actual behavior:**

- After calling “bakeNewCookie” I don’t see the new contract I created.

**Question:**

1. Do I actually create new Cookie contracts on the blockchain with this code? In the future I want users on a website to access the Cookies they have created and display them on a website.
2. Right now I’m trying to use the new contract address as the identifier to interact with them. Is there a better way to do it? I need a unique ID for each cookie that is tied to its information. Ideally I’d like to create a mapping of the new contracts but that doesn’t seem to be possible.
3. Why doesn’t the “myCookieAddress” function work as expected?

Thanks so much in advance for the help!

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Cookie {
    address public CookieAddress;
    string public CookieName;

    constructor() public {
        CookieAddress = address(this);
    }

    function theCookieInfo() view public returns(address, string memory) {
        return (CookieAddress, CookieName);
    }

}


contract Baker is Cookie {

    address public BakerAddress;
    address[] public CookieAddresses;

    constructor() public {
        BakerAddress = address(this);
    }    

    function bakeNewCookie(string memory _name) public returns(bool) {
        new Cookie();
        Cookie.CookieName = _name;
        CookieAddresses.push(CookieAddress);
        return true;
    }

    function getCookieArray() view public returns(address[] memory) {
        return CookieAddresses;
    }

    function myCookieAddress(address _addressOfCookie) view public returns(string memory) {
        Cookie my_cookie = Cookie(_addressOfCookie);
        return my_cookie.CookieName();
  }    


}
```

Comment: You most certainly can't do `Cookie.CookieName = _name`. I suggest that you simply add the name to the constructor of `Cookie`.

Comment: @goodvibration If I add the name to the constructor of `Cookie`, will I be able to define it upon contract initialization/creation? The idea is to be able to identify these new Cookie contracts with names chosen upon creation.